# Проверте пожалуйста команду( При запуске сразу выключается )

Tags: python

```
import random

x= random.randint(1, 5)

def Retry():

    y=input("Готов?(да, нет):")

    if y=="да":

    print("Компьютер загадывает чило")

    z=input("Введите число:")
        if z==x:

            print("Угадал!")
        else

        print("Думай")

    b=input("Продолжим?(да, нет):")

        If b=="да":
```

Retry()

Comment: У вас кавычка не закрытая в `z=input`

Comment: Всё равно не запускается)

Comment: после `if y=="да":` добавьте отступы, последний input() замените на Retry()

Comment: Сделал программа всё-равно не запускается

Comment: @ДимонДимоныч, запускайте из консоли и читайте ошибки.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

О том, что вам, очевидно, забыли рассказать про отступы в Python и про то, что после else надо ставить двоеточие   -  я умолчу. А про то, как работает функция и ее вызов рассказали?

```
import random
x= random.randint(1, 5)
def Retry():
    y=input("Готов?(да, нет):")
    if y=="да":
        print("Компьютер загадывает число")
        z=int(input("Введите число:"))
        if z==x:
            print("Угадал!")
        else:
            print("Не угадал :-(")           
b='да'
while b=='да':
    Retry()
    b=input("Продолжим?(да, нет):")
```

> Готов?(да, нет):нет
>
> Продолжим?(да, нет):да
>
> Готов?(да, нет):да Компьютер загадывает чило
>
> Введите число:7 Не угадал :-(
>
> Продолжим?(да, нет):да
>
> Готов?(да, нет):нет
>
> Продолжим?(да, нет):нет

Comment: Пока учусь) Хоть и на ошибках, но спасибо за помощь

Comment: Но при проверке ни одно число не подходит... Странно

Comment: А вам видимо не рассказали, что input() выдает строку, а не число.

Answer (score 0):

Так работает

```
if int(z)==int(x):
```

Comment: x необязательно, оно уже число.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
from random import randint


def dice_roll():
    num = randint(1, 5)
    negative_answers = ['no', 'No', 'n', 'N']
    print('Компьютер загадал число от 1 до 5')
    guess = int(input('Попробуйте угадать: '))

    if num == guess:
        print('Поздраяляю!!! Вы угадали')
    else:
        print(f'Вам не повезло :((\nБыло загадано число {num}, Вы указали {guess}')

    return not input('Играем дальше [Y|n]: ') in negative_answers


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while dice_roll(): pass
```