# Ошибка в результате при проверке if

Tags: python-3.x

увидел сегодня проблему, и попытался сам разобраться и заодно помочь автору, т.к я еще совсем новичок. Пришел приблизительно к тому же ответу, что был дан в посте:
    https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1059979/364194
    Вопрос: если открыть код из ответа и протестировать его, он постоянно выдает результат:"Не угадал :-(  ",

```
import random
x= random.randint(1, 5)
def Retry():
    y=input("Готов?(да, нет):")
    if y=="да":
        print("Компьютер загадывает чило")
        z=input("Введите число:")
        if z==x:
            print("Угадал!")
        else:
            print("Не угадал :-(")

b='да'
while b=='да':
    Retry()
    b=input("Продолжим?(да, нет):")
```

Хотелось бы узнать в чем ошибка "правильного" решения, заранее большое спасибо!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скопирую сюда нужную часть кода.

```
import random
x= random.randint(1, 5)
def Retry():
    y=input("Готов?(да, нет):")
    if y=="да":
        print("Компьютер загадывает чило")
        z=input("Введите число:")
        if z==x:
            print("Угадал!")
        else:
            print("Не угадал :-(")
```

Ошибка в том, что `x` - число, а `z` - строка. А сравнение числа со строкой всегда дает False.

`input()` всегда выдает строку и, чтобы получить (целое) число, нужно использовать функцию `int()`.

Исправленная часть кода:

```
z = int(input("Введите число:"))
```

Или в другом месте

```
if int(z) == x:
```

Или можно наоборот x превратить в строку `str(x)` :) Так даже ещё лучше - выполнение не прекратится, если вместо целого числа введут что-нибудь другое.